# HBase Hive Integration - Error

Tags: hadoop, hive, hbase, bigdata

When I try to Load Data from HDFS to HBase using Hive logical tables, I am facing the following problem. I am new for hadoop and not able to trace the error,.I am using CDH4 VM,

Creating a new HBase table which is managed by Hive

```
CREATE TABLE hive_hbasetable(key int, value string)
STORED BY 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.hbase.HBaseStorageHandler'
WITH SERDEPROPERTIES ("hbase.columns.mapping" = ":key,cf1:val")
TBLPROPERTIES ("hbase.table.name" = "hivehbasek1");
```

Hbase shell Output

```
hbase(main):002:0> list 
TABLE
hivebasek1
mysql_cityclimate

2 row(s) in 0.2470 seconds
```

I created a logical table hive_logictable in Hive

```
CREATE TABLE hive_logictable (foo INT, bar STRING) row format delimited fields terminated by ',';
```

Inserting data in hive_logictable from HDFS.

```
cat TextFile.txt
100,value1
101,value2
102,value3
103,value4
104,value5
105,value6

LOAD DATA LOCAL INPATH '/home/cloudera/TextFile.txt' OVERWRITE INTO TABLE hive_logictable;
```

Loading data into HBase table using Hive.

```
INSERT OVERWRITE TABLE hive_hbasetable SELECT * FROM hive_logictable;
```

Below are the error messages throwing....

```
Total MapReduce jobs = 1
Launching Job 1 out of 1
Number of reduce tasks is set to 0 since there's no reduce operator
Starting Job = job_201501200937_0004, Tracking URL = http://0.0.0.0:50030/jobdetails.jsp?jobid=job_201501200937_0004
Kill Command = /usr/lib/hadoop/bin/hadoop job  -kill job_201501200937_0004
Hadoop job information for Stage-0: number of mappers: 1; number of reducers: 0
2015-01-20 10:38:07,412 Stage-0 map = 0%,  reduce = 0%
2015-01-20 10:38:52,822 Stage-0 map = 100%,  reduce = 100%
Ended Job = job_201501200937_0004 with errors
Error during job, obtaining debugging information...
Job Tracking URL: http://0.0.0.0:50030/jobdetails.jsp?jobid=job_201501200937_0004
Examining task ID: task_201501200937_0004_m_000002 (and more) from job job_201501200937_0004

Task with the most failures(4): 
-----
Task ID:
  task_201501200937_0004_m_000000

URL:
  http://localhost.localdomain:50030/taskdetails.jsp?jobid=job_201501200937_0004&tipid=task_201501200937_0004_m_000000
-----
Diagnostic Messages for this Task:
java.lang.RuntimeException: Error in configuring object
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.setJobConf(ReflectionUtils.java:109)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.setConf(ReflectionUtils.java:75)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.newInstance(ReflectionUtils.java:133)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runOldMapper(MapTask.java:413)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:332)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child$4.run(Child.java:268)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:396)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1438)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child.main(Child.java:262)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.ja

FAILED: Execution Error, return code 2 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.MapRedTask
MapReduce Jobs Launched: 
Job 0: Map: 1   HDFS Read: 0 HDFS Write: 0 FAIL
Total MapReduce CPU Time Spent: 0 msec
```

End of Error Message.

Answer (score 0):

Could you please check if the atomic insert works fine on the HIVE table ? And share the results ?